# Есть ли библиотека для конвертации из xls в sql?

Tags: python, xls, mysql

Ребят, не подскажите, есть ли библиотека для конвертации из xls в sql 
или самому лепипть  что-то  из import xlrd?

По сколько модератор убрал из заголовка слово (Python) , то напоминаю что речь идёт о языке Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. О принадлежности вопроса к используемой технологии и языку говорят теги.
2. Все же придется использовать xlrd, но работать с ним достаточно просто: [пример](http://mherman.org/blog/2012/09/30/import-data-from-excel-into-mysql-using-python/) и [еще пример с ютуба](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLXFEQLCogM)